# NodeFilter and Partitions

Tags: ignite

I am trying to figure out a "easy" way to do multinode with apache Ignite. I understand that the right way to do is to define an affinity but that is quite a complex task. Therefore I would like some "simple" multinode in the cluster. Let me clear that I understand the limitations in terms of scalability of what I am asking.

So instead of having a affinity that would force me to change all the keys and thus massively change the code, I would like to use the nodeFilter of a cache to tag a cache to a particular node and thus I would put all the caches of a same group in the same node. Then I would to run all the processes in the same node for these specific caches sending one job per partition (same as I am doing when I have an affinity) Then for another parallel job, I would create all the caches on another node and thus use the other node.

Now here is my question and my problem. When I enable the nodeFilter, I was expecting the data of the caches to be spread on the partitions local to a cache. So if I would have 1024 partitions in total, node-1 would have 512 and node-2 would have 512. Thus my cache would use the 512 partitions of node-1 (if nodeFilter to set to node-1). After that I can easily use the partition mechanism to spread the work. That does not work because the affinity returns 0 partitions. Furthermore, the forDataNodes() method for that cache answers 0 as well.

Can somebody explain the behavior and point me in the right direction?

```
public class TestIgnite {


    private static final String CONSISTENT_ID = "node1";
    private static Ignite ignite;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public static void prepareTest() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("IGNITE_OVERRIDE_CONSISTENT_ID", CONSISTENT_ID);
        Ignition.start(IgniteConfigurations.loadDefaultConfiguration());
        ignite = Ignition.ignite(ProcessingConfiguration.GRID_NAME);
        ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE);
        Thread.sleep(5000);     
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testNodeFilter()  {

        
        String CACHE_NAME = "CACHE_NAME";
        String CONSISTENT_ID = "node1";
        CacheConfiguration<String, String> ccfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(CACHE_NAME);
        ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        ccfg.setBackups(0);

        ccfg.setAffinity(new RendezvousAffinityFunction());
        
        ccfg.setDataRegionName("main");
        ccfg.setGroupName("main");
        ccfg.setSqlEscapeAll(true);
        ccfg.setCopyOnRead(false);
        ccfg.setEventsDisabled(true);
        ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);       
        org.apache.ignite.configuration.NearCacheConfiguration<String, String> cfg = new org.apache.ignite.configuration.NearCacheConfiguration<>();
        cfg.setNearEvictionPolicyFactory(new LruEvictionPolicyFactory<>(100));
        ccfg.setNearConfiguration(cfg);
        ccfg.setGroupName("main");
        
//      Enabling the following 2 lines results in the affinity to not work anymore
//      List<ClusterNode> nodes =ignite.cluster().nodes().stream()
//              .filter(n -> n.consistentId().equals(CONSISTENT_ID)).collect(Collectors.toList());
//      ccfg.setNodeFilter(node -> node.consistentId().equals(nodes.get(0)));
            
        ignite.createCache(ccfg);
        
        ClusterGroup grpCache = ignite.cluster().forCacheNodes(CACHE_NAME);
        System.out.println("Cache group size : " + grpCache.nodes().size());
        ClusterGroup grpData = ignite.cluster().forDataNodes(CACHE_NAME);
// When node Filter is enabled, the data group size is 0
        System.out.println("Data group size : " + grpData.nodes().size());

        
        int[] p = ignite.affinity(CACHE_NAME).allPartitions(grpCache.node());
        System.out.println("# of partitions : " + p.length);
// When node Filter is enabled, there are no partitions
        assertEquals(1024, p.length);
        
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        ignite.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code example, I can assume that you have issues with the baseline topology:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/baseline-topology

```
    Ignition.start(IgniteConfigurations.loadDefaultConfiguration());
    ignite = Ignition.ignite(ProcessingConfiguration.GRID_NAME);
    ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE);
```

After first activation you will generate baseline with only one node (if cluster is using persistence). After starting second node, that node will be out of baseline.

As the result all data will be on the first node. You filter will work only when both nodes will be in the baseline. You can add your second node using:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#adding-nodes-to-baseline-topology

In this situation the following code will return only one node:

```
ClusterGroup grpCache = ignite.cluster().forCacheNodes(CACHE_NAME);
```

So all you filter logic will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @andrei for your help. After having tried with the node filter to create a "node" affinity and no succeeding. I finally solved it with the standard affinity mechanism (implementing `AffinityFunction`).

That is I implemented an affinity function and assigned the total number of partitions (1024) / number of nodes (assume 4) hence 256 partitions per node. I believe that would then work even with a change of topology because the method `public List<List<ClusterNode>> assignPartitions(AffinityFunctionContext affCtx)` would then be called in that case. Hence in `assignPartitions` I assigned blocs of 256 partitions to each of the 4 nodes. Then, I calculate the partition hash on 256 basis (not 1024) and then OR it to add 0,256,512,768 depending on the node.

```
if (mask >= 0) {
    int h = key.hashCode();
    return (((h) ^ (h >>> 16)) & maskForRangePerNode) | shiftForBinding;
}
```

with

```
maskForRangePerNode = (partitions() / nodes.size()) - 1;
shiftForBinding = nodeIndex * numberOfPartPerNode;
```